# Create [microsoft-dynamics-webapi] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

### Overview

Microsoft Dynamics Web API is the new standard for interacting with Microsoft Dynamics.  According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt608128.aspx#bkmk_webapi)

> Compared to the Organization service, the Web API provides better
>   compatibility across a wide variety of programming languages,
>   platforms, and devices. The Web API implements the OData (Open Data
>   Protocol) v4. OData is an OASIS standard for building and consuming
>   RESTful APIs over rich data sources. You can learn more at the OData
>   protocol and the OASIS standard websites. Because the Web API is built
>   on open standards, you aren’t required to use client libraries
>   specific to Microsoft Dynamics 365. You can choose to compose HTTP
>   requests for specific operations or use third-party libraries to
>   generate classes for whatever language or platform you want to use.
>   View a list of available libraries. Eventually the Web API will
>   replace the Organization service and Organization Data service but
>   both of these existing web services will be available to enable a
>   gradual transition to a single Web API. The Web API should be your
>   first choice for new development that will support Microsoft Dynamics
>   365 and future versions of Microsoft Dynamics 365 (online). Use the
>   Web API for any projects that access Microsoft Dynamics 365 data with
>   code that doesn’t run on the server, including XmlHttpRequests from
>   web resources and form scripts that run in Microsoft Dynamics 365
>   application clients. At this time you can’t easily use the Web API for
>   code that runs on the server, such as in plug-ins or workflow
>   assemblies.

### Wiki Excerpt

A tag for questions related to the [Microsoft Dynamics Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593051.aspx). This tag should be used for questions about using the Web API in your code.  Do not use this tag for questions related to using Microsoft Dynamics software (use [microsoft-dynamics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics) instead).

### Related Questions

[Get child data Microsoft Dynamics WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394263/get-child-data-microsoft-dynamics-webapi)

Comment: Is [tag:microsoft-dynamics] not good enough? "This tag can cover any of the products in the Dynamics family"

Comment: @Michael I think it would be good to draw the distinction between the software itself and the API.  We've already set the precedent with [tag:youtube] and [tag:youtube-api]

Comment: I'm not thrilled by the wiki excerpt. It should explain when and why the tag should be used on a question. Your current version reads as a marketing blurb

Comment: @rene How does the new wiki excerpt look?

Comment: it is a very small tag.  Dreadful answer rate, only 1 in 10 questions got an answer last week.  Creating more tags is liable to just make this worse, making it harder still for answerers to find questions and for the machine to push a question to a specific user's Interesting page view.  Not a great idea.

Answer (score 2):

I have created the tag [microsoft-dynamics-webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-dynamics-webapi) for you on the question you provided.

I also created the excerpt you offered.

There is no tag wiki yet. Consider adding one with useful guidance for users of the tag.
By no means copy text verbatim from a Microsoft site or any other resource for that matter, it is **plagiarism** which is **not acceptable, ever**. On top of that, those text are seldom a good fit as the wiki should elaborate how the tag is used, how it relates to other tags, common questions, which information is needed in a question, links to useful off-site resources, etc. All things that are unique to Stack Overflow can't possible exist already somewhere else.

Now please go and make sure this tag doesn't get nominated to be [burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-burninating-tags) because I hate cleaning up a mess I started my self....

Comment: What do you mean by "go and make sure this tag doesn't get nominated to be burninated"?  Are you just saying use it frequently?

Comment: @TimHutchison I'm saying use it correctly and only for what it is intended for. All tags for sure start out with the promise of being an awesome tag but if not monitored or applied correctly, in the end it is going to hurt and removing the tag or cleaning up after a few years of misuse  is not always fun, specially because I'm (and the SOCVR chatroom) often involved in the cleaning up ... you'll find enough evidence on meta...

Comment: I know you won't, but as a reminder, please don't make the tag wiki a copy of that text from Microsoft's site. Plagiarism is not welcome.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan better safe then sorry so I added that warning explicitly to my answer.